# py_object does not release referred object reliably

Tags: python, ctypes

When reassigning a ctypes py_object the previous assigned object will be released (as expected).

But when getting a pointer to a py_object and then resolving this pointer, the resulting py_object does not work as expected (=ref counter will not change):

```
from sys import getrefcount
from ctypes import *

pyobj = 'any python object'
ct_ref = py_object(pyobj)
ct_ref2 = pointer(ct_ref).contents

refCntBefore = getrefcount(pyobj)
ct_ref2.value = 'another python object'   # when replace ct_ref2 with ct_ref everything will work!
assert getrefcount(pyobj) < refCntBefore, 'object was not released'
```

On my system I use Python 2.7.10 32bit (Windows).

I assume this is a bug in ctypes, so honestly said I don't believe in a solution. But maybe anyone with a workaround? thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: how is that a bug? You're specifically circumventing python's automatic refcounting by using the `contents` of a ctypes `pointer`.

Comment: You have a worse problem. `ct_ref2` doesn't own its buffer, so setting `ct_ref2.value` modifies the referent of `ct_ref`, but `ct_ref._objects` still references `pyobj` instead of what it points at now. This is fine so far because `ct_ref2._b_base_` (i.e. the `pointer(ct_ref)`) references `ct_ref`, `pyobj`, and `'another python object'` in its `_objects` dict. But if you `del ct_ref2`, that also clears its `_b_base_`. The refcount of `'another python object'` goes to 0 and it gets deallocated. Now if you access `ct_ref` the process will likely segfault.